# CSS: Truncate label with ellipsis, but always display 'required indicator'

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a horizontal form which uses Bootstrap3's standard classes for styling.
However, I have three more requirements:

- Labels should be truncated with a "..." in the end as soon as they would wrap
- If the input field is required, an Asterisk (*) should be displayed after the last letter of the Label. **And should not be affected by the truncation.**
- The HTML Markup mustn't be touched. (T___T)

**Is this possible with a CSS-only solution?** Thank you so much in advance, guys!

```css
.control-label {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.form-group[required] > label:after {
  content: " * ";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="form-horizontal" style="max-width: 700px;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" required>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputRequired">Required:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputRequired" placeholder="Required"/>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group" required>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputRequired2">Required with long Label:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputRequired2" placeholder="Required with long Label"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make your own custom "truncate" class and attach a absolute "*" asteriks when needed like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/rrjruf82/

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div type='text' class='label truncate'> Add text here more more more     </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.truncate {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.label {
  max-width: 120px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.label:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 4px;
  content: '*';
  color: red;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply :)
I have actually tried something similiar already, but the problem with this one is that the asteriks will always be displayed at the very right of the Label (so directly attached to the left side of the input field)
So if the label is shorter than the max-width, the Asterisk will still be next tot he input field instead of the label.

Actually I was looking for some CSS selectors that might be able to help with this, but I was not able to find anything that helped me

Answer (score 0):

You should had the following rules to your asterisk.
Like so :

```
.form-group[required] > label:after {
   content: " * ";
   color: red;
   overflow: visible;
   white-space: normal;
   text-overflow: clip;
}
```

I would advice you to put absolute positioning on it too.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

Sorry for some reason the need for a verbose label never came to mind (isn't "verbose label" an oxymoron?). I have revised my answer to better suit your needs. It involves a little JS, but works better than I had anticipated. The basic idea is this:

- Add an inline element (e.g. `<span>`, `<i>`, `<b>`, etc.) inside the `<label>`
- Now when the macho asteriX is inserted within the `<label>` via `:after` pseudo-class, it will be placed after the inline element.
- So this element serves as a "buffer" that protects macho from being overwritten.

#### SNIPPET 2

```js
var fgrp = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group')[2];

var clbl = document.querySelectorAll('.control-label')[2];

var atX = document.createElement('span');

fgrp.classList.add('ellipse');

clbl.appendChild(atX);
```

```css
.control-label {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.form-group[required] > label:after {
  content: " ✱ ";
  color: red;
}

.ellipse *:last-of-type {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="form-horizontal" style="max-width: 700px;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" required>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputRequired">Required:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputRequired" placeholder="Required"/>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group" required>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputRequired2">Required with long Label~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputRequired2" placeholder="Required with long Label"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

### OLD

The technique I use is  simple CSS. I used JS just to generate some paragraphs to demonstrate the ellipse. That's the way I roll when I deal with a restricted HTML/JS usage. :P

BTW, I traded in that small asterix for a macho V8 1000 Horse-powered asteriX.

#### SNIPPET 1

```js
var text = ['Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.',

  'Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?',

  'At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.',

  'Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae.',

  'Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima',

  'Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?'
];



var s = document.createElement('section');

s.classList.add('ellipse');

document.body.appendChild(s);

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

  var p = document.createElement('p');

  p.innerHTML = text[i];

  s.appendChild(p);
}
```

```css
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 500 16px/1.428'Raleway';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
form {
  margin: 50px 20px;
}
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

.control-label {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.form-group[required] > label:after {
  content: " ✱ ";
  color: red;
}
/* Demo #3~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

.ellipse *:last-of-type {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
section {
  padding: 20px;
}
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="form-horizontal" style="max-width: 700px;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputEmail3">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
      <input type="email" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" required>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputRequired">Required:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputRequired" placeholder="Required" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" required>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputRequired2">Required with long Label:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputRequired2" placeholder="Required with long Label" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi zer00ne! thank you for your reply - I like your monster macho asterisk :D
Regarding the solution however, I'm afraid that I don't really get your point. Or did you suggest dealing with the "CSS only"-restriction by using JS in order to make a new ellipse function?

Comment: @Rebecca nah, I was being a smart@ss. I used JS because I could and you can as well. Fight the tyranny of WP, Django, Durpal, and all of those CMSs (Crappy Messy Sh*tty). The ellipse style is in there and stands alone. The rest is bonus. ;-) . `ellipse *:last-of-type {...`